# Why Can't Download Eclipse ADT in the second time?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-adt, download

I deleted Eclipse ADT as it was not responding and getting stuck and I wanted to download it again **but when it gets here http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=adt nothing happens** as I remember the first time I downloaded it when it gets to that page it start downloading alone.

BTW I am using windows 7 x64.

Please help me and tell me why that happened?

Comment: ... Go to the download part.

Comment: this is the download part.. the link which I put there, when we click it the download should start immediately..

Comment: No, not really. You linked to the installation page. The download page is http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. Your link is what you see *after* you download. On the left you'll see navigation links. The big one at the top says "Download". It links to the download part.

Comment: Go to this link - https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean first setup or ADT bundle and backup your workspace.
Then download ADT Bundle from here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download
Just extract it and use it.